# как можно сделать простой fullpage scroll на jquery без плагинов?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, fullpage

что нибудь самое примитивное, никаких супер сложных функций, пожалуйста :D

я тут попыталась сделать пример, но не смогла сообразить что делать дальше после прокрутки из первой страницы во вторую:

```js
$(function(){
  var $win = $(window);
  $win.on("scroll", function () {
   var top = $win.scrollTop();
   if(top>300){
    $('.p1').css({'height':-top/4 + 'px','transition':'800ms ease'})
   }
   

  });
 })
```

```css
section {
  background-color: red;
  height: 100vh;
}

section:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: blue
}

.p2 {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%
}

.p3, .p4, .p5 {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="p1">1</section>
<section class="p2">2</section>
<section class="p3">3</section>
<section class="p4">3</section>
<section class="p5">3</section>
```

должно получиться типо так:
https://codepen.io/tutsplus/full/VvZXMP/

Comment: А зачем изобретать велосипед?

Comment: Но... там же... всё есть

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnePageScroll без плагина только на **jQuery**.

```js
let currentLocation = 'firstPage';
let autoScrolling = false;

let [firstHeight,secondHeight,thirdHeight] = [$('#firstPage').offset().top,
 $('#secondPage').offset().top,
 $('#thirdPage').offset().top];

$(document).scroll(e => {
    let scrolled = $(window).scrollTop();
    // Если user поскроллил
    if (!autoScrolling) {
     if (scrolled > 1 && currentLocation == 'firstPage') {
            scrollPage(secondHeight, 'secondPage');
        } else if (scrolled > secondHeight + 1 && currentLocation == 'secondPage') {
            scrollPage(thirdHeight, 'thirdPage');
        } else if (scrolled < thirdHeight - 1 && currentLocation == 'thirdPage') {
            scrollPage(secondHeight, 'secondPage');
        } else if (scrolled < secondHeight - 1 && currentLocation == 'secondPage') {
            scrollPage(firstHeight, 'firstPage');
        }
    }

    function scrollPage(nextHeight, page){
      currentLocation = page; autoScrolling = true;
      $('body,html').animate({scrollTop:nextHeight}, 500, () => {
          autoScrolling = false;
      });
    }
})
```

```css
*{
 padding: 0;
 margin: 0;
}
html,body{
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
}
.page{
 width: 100%;
 line-height: 100vh;
 text-align: center;
}
header{
 position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
 <h1></h1>
</header>
<article>
 <div class="page" id="firstPage">
  <h2>первый</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="page" id="secondPage">
  <h2>второй</h2>
 </div>
 <div class="page" id="thirdPage">
  <h2>третий</h2>
 </div>
</article>
```

Comment: оо круто!! но почему ту на втором слайде не останавливается, а сразу проходит на третий. у вас тоже так?

Comment: @valeria нет у меня работает все отлично.Проверял в Firefox и в Chrome.не забудте принять ответ если оно вам помогло :)